# easy way to install Python on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, python

The standard way to install Python on Windows seems to be run the executable and then fiddle with the environmental variables. eg see [here](http://blog.sadphaeton.com/2009/01/20/python-development-windows-part-1installing-python.html) or [here](http://vimeo.com/18197276).

The people I deal with would be intimidated having to modify their environmental variables. So how can someone install Python on Windows and run Python scripts without having to fiddle them?

Perhaps an installer that sets the environmental variables, or a batch script that uses the full paths?

Comment: What environmental variables? If you just want to double-click on `.py` files to run them, you don't need environmental variables; you only need to set `.py` files to be opened with Python.

Comment: You only need to set the environment variables if you want to run python from the command line without typing out the full path to the executable. Probably not something that a user will be doing unless they're fairly savvy anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.3 there's a new [option](http://docs.python.org/py3k/using/windows.html#windows-path-mod) for automatically adding Python to `PATH` environment variable.

> Besides using the automatically created start menu entry for the
>   Python interpreter, you might want to start Python in the command
>   prompt. As of Python 3.3, the installer has an option to set that up
>   for you.
>
> At the “Customize Python 3.3” screen, an option called “Add python.exe
>   to search path” can be enabled to have the installer place your
>   installation into the %PATH%. This allows you to type python to run
>   the interpreter. Thus, you can also execute your scripts with command
>   line options, see Command line documentation.

However Python's installer on Windows by default associates Python files with Python interpreter so users can run Python scripts just by clicking Python script or a link to it.